# Space Opera Novel Series ID - Probably Read in 2003-2010

Tags: story-identification, novel, powers

I'm looking for the name of a series of space opera novels I read some time ago, probably between 2003 and 2010.

- It may have been published quite a few years before I read it, I don't think it was new at the time.
- I borrowed the novels from the local library, but I can't find them in its catalogue.
- I think the covers were fairly dark and plain, though there may have been some artwork on them.
- There was a totalitarian empire that controlled most planets, possibly ruled by a queen.
- There was no mention of Earth, the solar system or other real planets, the setting was completely fictional.
- There were people with psychic/psionic powers, referred to as something like "psi". These people were second-class citizens or slaves.
- Spaceships were used to travel between worlds. I'm not sure what kind of FTL technology they had, if any.
- Beyond the edge of the empire was some kind of "dark space", where there was no light.
- There were some horror themes: When travelling in dark space in one of the novels, a ships crew experienced strange thoughts and hallucinations. I remember finding this quite scary at the time.

Does anyone know which series this could be?

This isn't a duplicate of [this question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/56888/book-centered-around-a-labyrinth-maze), since the two questions are about different parts of the same series (the first and second episodes).

Comment: Take a look at this [guide](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/a/9337/68872) to help jog your memory and [edit](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/posts/155079/edit) any more details. Specifically things like when you read it, or where? Also, take a look at our [tour](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/tour) to get a better understanding of our site and earn your first [badge](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/badges)!

Comment: I've already read the guide and provided all the details I can (including when I read it).

Comment: Please don't take offence, it's just a stock comment I use for new Story ID questions :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Book centered around a labyrinth/maze](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/56888/book-centered-around-a-labyrinth-maze)

Comment: @Otis I would personally go the other way on this particular dupe.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You've summarised fairly accurately the background of the [Deathstalker](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deathstalker_(series)) novels, by Simon R Green.

They're set in the far future; the empire of man is huge and old, ruled over by the Empress Lionstone. There's no mention of Earth that I can recall.

There are citizens with psi powers known as espers, who are treated as second class citizens at best; slaves at worst. There's also a zone of stars, extinguished in a long-ago war, called the Darkvoid; from where some nasty aliens appear to attack the Empire.

The first book in the series is Deathstalker. There are a total of five in the main series, another three in a trilogy that is set a couple of decades later, and three shorter, prequel novels , too.

Comment: That looks like it, thanks. Your answer was slightly more detailed than Alith's, so I accepted it.

Answer (score 6):

I'm not sure but this sounds like the Deathstslker series or the prequel novels Mistworld, Ghostworld and Hellworld.

These were written by Simon R Green with a wiki link here https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deathstalker_(series)
Will try and add more details later today when I'm back at my computer but the elements you mention are all present from memory.

Comment: That looks like it, thanks.