# Older Sci-fi book set in an 'Outlaw City'. Mute thief on a cold planet

Tags: story-identification, novel

The city, whose name I can't remember, was in a pretty cold location. Extremely cold. There was a river going through it. It was mentioned once or twice because there was a character of a thief (he was mute, I think) and he had to have this selfheated suit to walk and jump and parkour his way around. I don't think he was the main character.

This city was run by a council of four individuals I believe. One of them was an older woman, one I don't remember at all, and two other men, one of whom was an old veteran (hero of the city) who defended this place against some beast from the wild, I think they were called somethinghounds (because of course they were).

The other man on the council was a slippery disgusting guy, who was selling people for organs. He had these containers full of tiny machines to separate each organ system so they could be sold. Than I remember was mechanical or genetically modified human, the name had to do something with Hades or Pluto, and he was killed by a mercenary. I remember that the mercenary cut off his head with his energy shield, after faking its powerdown.

The last character I remember was a girl, she had a of plague in her name or some kind of disease, because she was transferring this disease in her body. She might have some psychic capabilities, but I'm not sure about that one.

Comment: possibly the same as https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/155079/space-opera-novel-series-id-probably-read-in-2003-2010

Answer (score 12):

The book series [Deathstalker](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deathstalker_(series)) by Simon R. Green has a deaf-mute thief named Cat who lives on an ice planet.

> Tall and slender, Cat was a deaf mute, and quite possibly the best
>   burglar in the city. He was supposedly retired, now that Cyder had the
>   means to keep him, but roof runners of his quality were always in
>   demand, and he liked to keep busy.

*'Clonelegging'* of organs is big business

> She stopped and looked around her, surrounded by hundreds upon hundreds of human organs and tissues, enough to fill a dozen battlegrounds, and every one of them worthless. Contaminated beyond saving by a smuggled virus. That was what you got for making enemies in the clonelegging business.

The rest of your description would match most of the sequels.

Comment: Sounds like the Mistworld novel from the Twighlight of the Empire series - https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/629072.Mistworld

Comment: The plague carrier would be Typhoid Mary